# How do you make a flashing effect for a turtle in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a very basic version of a turtle fight simulator.
I want to create a flash effect like how they do in the Pokemon games when the opposing pokemon gets hit.
How can I do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
import turtle

#Writes the title
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-300,100)
pen.write("A Turtle Fight Simulator" , font=("Times New Roman", 40, "normal"))

#Creates the blue turtle
Blueturtle = turtle.Turtle()
Blueturtle.shape("turtle")
Blueturtle.color("blue")
Blueturtle.penup()
Blueturtle.goto(-200,0)
Blueturtle.speed(10)

#Creates the red turtle
Redturtle = turtle.Turtle()
Redturtle.shape("turtle")
Redturtle.left(180)
Redturtle.color("red")
Redturtle.penup()
Redturtle.goto(100,0)
Redturtle.speed(100)

bluepoints = 300
redpoints = 300

#Asks each user for a number between 1 through 10
keepPlaying = True
while keepPlaying:
   userBlue = int(input("UserBlue - Pick a number between 0 and 9 to use a move:"))
   userRed = int(input("UserRed - Pick a number between 0 and 9 to use a move:"))


  if userBlue == 0:
    Blueturtle.forward(300)
    Redturtle.hideturtle(20)
    Redturtle.showturtle(10)
    Redturtle.hideturtle(20)
    Redturtle.showturtle(10)
    Blueturtle.backward(300)
    print("It's not very effective...")
    print("The red turtle lost 30 hitpoints!")
    redpoints = redpoints - 30
    print("Red turtle now has", redpoints , "hitpoints")


wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you edit your code down to focus on the code you have tried to create the flashing effect?